# Why does "const extern" give an error?

Tags: c, gcc, global-variables, constants, extern

The following piece of code working fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int foo; // Without constant
int foo = 42;

int main() 
{
    printf("%d\n",foo);
    return 0;
}
```

But, the following piece of code give an error:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const extern int foo; // With constant
int foo = 42;

int main() 
{
    printf("%d\n",foo);
    return 0;
}
```

So, why does `const extern` give an error?

Comment: Why not? Why did you expect to be able to redeclare the same identifier with different type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard says:
C11-§6.7/4

> All declarations in the same scope that refer to the same object or function shall specify compatible types

`const int` and `int` are not compatible for the same object `foo` in the same scope.

Answer (score 4):

These two declarations are contradictory:

```
const extern int foo; // With constant
int foo = 42;
```

The first one declares `foo` as const, and the second one declares it as non const.

Error messages:

```
prog.cpp:4:5: error: conflicting declaration
   ‘int foo’ int foo = 42; 
         ^~~
 prog.cpp:3:18: note: previous declaration as ‘const int foo’
    const extern int foo; // With constant 
                     ^~~
```

Answer (score 3):

You say `foo` is `const` and then try to change its constness with the other declaration.
Do this and you should be fine.

```
  const extern int foo; // With constant
  const int foo = 42;
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is not what the OP does: `int foo = 42;` is not a modification of `foo`, it is a declaration with an initializer. The problem is the definitions are incompatible. `const volatile int foo = 42;` would have been an error too.

Comment: Surprisingly, `static const int foo = 42;` would be compatible.

Comment: @chqrlie Correct.Thanks.Please feel free to edit this answer if its still wrongly worded.